# Formatting across multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Trying to set formatting that will add a line (border) depending on the "rank" entered as shown below. Tried the following with conditional formatting by formula with no results.

With A18:T18 selected

B17 = D2

[image]

Comment: Conditional formatting will likely do what you want. Your question is very unclear. what does the rank have to do with the highlighted stores ("FA")? Does your screencap show the desired result? If no, can you provide us with the expected output?

Comment: The highlighted store is a separate issue.  In this instance, the store (FA) has an overall store ranking of 4, the columns you see are separate categories within that store.  If store "FA" is ranked 4th overall, but 9th within a specific area, that presents a teaching opportunity.  The red line indicates the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition with this formula:

```
=$C11-1=$D$2
```

But place the line *above* the cell (and not below)

It should give you the result you want for all ranks, except the last one.